# "Invalid constructor name" error in Dart/Flutter

Tags: android, oop, mobile, dart, flutter

I'm starting to study flutter, which in turn uses Dart as its language, so I can say I'm learning both at the same time. I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 for that.

I've been building an app as a proof of concept for work and have found an error that has dumbfounded me.

I have a custom class that is the basis of another class which contains a list of the first. This class will, subsequently, be used to feed a ListView in my app.

When I try to add a new element of that custom class to the list, I get an error message stating that the variable of the list I've created is an "invalid constructor name"! It's not eve supposed to be a constructor, so I don't get what is going on.

I don't know if I'm getting some of the language's features wrong or if my OOP knowledge (which is a bit rusty at the moment, and which I'm trying to get up to speed, after all I'm mainly a NATURAL/ADABAS programmer) is not yet good enough to get what I did wrong, so any insights would be most appreciated.

Here's a snippet of the code  with the classes in question.

```
class Aluno {
  final int numDiario;
  final String nomeAluno;
  final String codAluno;

  Aluno ({
    this.numDiario,
    this.nomeAluno,
    this.codAluno,
  });
}

class Alunos  {
  final _alunos = <Aluno>[];

  static int nDiario;

  static int _incNumDiario(){
    return nDiario++;
  }

  static var nAl = new WordPair.random();
  static String nomeAluno = '$nAl.first $nAl.second';

  Aluno aluno = new Aluno(numDiario: _incNumDiario(),nomeAluno:  nomeAluno, codAluno: nDiario.toString());

  _alunos.add(aluno); //Here's where the error happens!
}
```

And here's the error I get:

```
error: Invalid constructor name. (invalid_constructor_name at [dd_movel] lib\abas\frequencia\linha_presencao.dart:32)
```

This is the "flutter doctor" output:

```
C:\Users\p001385\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.1.5, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 6.1.7601], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Only static methods or variable can be used in class definition. You are trying to add a `Aluno` to the list in `Alunos` in definition, which is not . possible.

Comment: Oh! I See!! So if I created a method and added the new Aluno instance to the list inside this method it would work!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or initialize the list inside constructor.

```
Alunos() {
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno(numDiario: _incNumDiario(),nomeAluno:  nomeAluno, codAluno: nDiario.toString());
    _alunos.add(aluno); 
  }
```